# Laying out logistic function equation with Euler's number

Tags: logistic-regression

Sorry for the incredibly basic question. I've not studied maths but need to understand the how to formulate an equation for something I'm revising.

In the image below I cannot get the same result of 0.0924. I'm sure the result is correct but I cannot reproduce it because I don't know how to formulate the equation using a scientific calculator, ie any brackets, order of operations, etc. I have tried so many permutations but just cannot get the right result.

Please could someone lay out how this should be entered into a calculator as I need to use this formula repeatedly.

Using https://web2.0calc.com/

I have tried `e(-2.91+6.26*0.01)/1+e(-2.91+6.26*0.01)`

and `e-2.91+6.26*0.01/1+e-2.91+6.26*0.01`

The same on my scientific calculator.

[formula image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN4hI.png)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us your best attempt, with whatever parentheses you tried. You should also tell us what kinds of keys your calculator has (for example, is there an exp or ln?). If you need to use this often consider using a spreadsheet, or entering the formula in the google search bar - better than all that keypunching.

Comment: Question edited - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed 0.01 instead of 0.1, left out the power operator ^, and forgot to put brackets around the denominator. The following works:

```
e^(-2.91+6.26*0.1)/(1+e^(-2.91+6.26*0.1))
```

Comment: You can paste that line into the linked calculator, or into the google search bar.